# Replacing substring with dictionary value if it matches with the keys

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary and string as well, I want to replace the substring with the dictionary value. I'm using the following code, but not getting the expected result.

```
dict1 = {'name1': 'Orange', 'name2': 'Apple', 'name3': 'Carrot', 'name4': 'Mango'}
a ="Fruit: name1    Fruit: name2    Fruit: name5    Fruit: name3    Fruit: name5"
print(a)
a_new = ''
for key in dict1.keys():
    skey = a[a.find(': ') + 2 : a.find(' F')].strip()
    if skey == key:
        sval = dict1[key]
        a_new = a[ : a.find(': ') + 1] + sval + a[a.find(' F') : ]
print(a_new)
```

**Output of my code**

```
Fruit: name1     Fruit: name2     Fruit: name5     Fruit: name4     Fruit: name5 
Fruit:Orange Fruit: name2     Fruit: name5     Fruit: name4     Fruit: name5
```

**My expected output**

```
Fruit: name1     Fruit: name2     Fruit: name5     Fruit: name4     Fruit: name5 
Fruit: Orange     Fruit: Apple     Fruit: name5     Fruit: Carrot     Fruit: Mango
```

I appreciate your assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to match the substrings with the consecutive keys from first to last or want to check whether it matches with any keys?

Comment: I just want to check the substring matches with the dictionary keys or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you were very close to your expected output. I edited your codes somewhere and got your expected output, though you also can do it using a regular expression. `find`returns the first occurrence matches with the substring, in your case, you need to shift your `find` searching position.

```
find(substring, start_position, end_position)
```

**Modified code**

```
dict1 = {'name1': 'Orange', 'name2': 'Apple', 'name3': 'Carrot', 'name4': 'Mango'}
a ="Fruit: name1    Fruit: name2     Fruit: name5    Fruit: name3    Fruit: name5"
offset1 = 0
offset2 = 0
print(a)
for key in dict1.keys():
    skey = a[a.find(': ', offset1) + 2 : a.find(' F', offset2)].strip()
    if skey in dict1.keys():
        sval = dict1[key]
        a = a[ : a.find(': ', offset1) + 2] +sval + '\t' + a[a.find(' F', offset2) : ]
    offset1 = a.find(': ', offset1) + 1
    offset2 = a.find(" F", offset2) + 1
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
Fruit: name1    Fruit: name2     Fruit: name5    Fruit: name3    Fruit: name5
Fruit: Orange    Fruit: Apple    Fruit: name5    Fruit: Mango    Fruit: name5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to find the matches and the use that to replace matching words in the string.

```py
import re

dict1 = {'name1': 'Orange', 'name2': 'Apple', 'name3': 'Carrot', 'name4': 'Mango'}
a ="Fruit: name1 \
    Fruit: name2 \
    Fruit: name5 \
    Fruit: name4 \
    Fruit: name5 \
"
pattern = re.compile(r"\w+:\s+(\w+)")
match = re.findall(pattern, a)
for item in match:
    if item in dict1.keys():
        a = a.replace(item, dict1[item])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
'Fruit: Orange     Fruit: Apple     Fruit: name5     Fruit: Mango     Fruit: name5 '
```